# Running gps android

Tags: android, gps, location

Trying to create a running gps in android, using this code to calculate the distance between two points every second (at least that's what I think it's doing):

```
    gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled
                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                    final Handler h = new Handler();
                    final int delay = 1000; //milliseconds

                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                            Location locationA = new Location("point A");
                            final Location locationB = new Location("point B");

                            locationA.setLatitude(latitude);
                            locationA.setLongitude(longitude);
                            Timer t = new Timer();

                            h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {

                                    double latitude1 = gps.getLatitude();
                                    double longitude2 = gps.getLongitude();

                                    locationB.setLatitude(latitude1);
                                    locationB.setLongitude(longitude2);

                                }
                            }, delay);
                            float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);

                            finalDistance[0] = (finalDistance[0] + distance);

                            displayDistance.setText(String.valueOf(finalDistance[0]));

                            h.postDelayed(this, delay);


                        }
                    }, delay);
```

The distance changes more or less by the same increment whether I'm walking or not walking.

The distance I get is also a weird value, e.g.: 6.47875890357E9

My questions: 1)What unit is this distance in?

2)Am I getting some random gobbledigook because of crap programming skills?

Comment: 1. And what docs says? 2. Pretty much yes.

Comment: could u help me to make it less crap? i mean, does it actually do what i think it's doing in terms of getting two locations every second?

Comment: ok so it's in meters, but then why des the value increase even tho i'm not moving?

Comment: The value increases because of the GPS's accuracy - despite not been moved, the GPS's receives different location in each new reading. The values should be very close to each other, but in accumulates. You can use your device's accelerometer to decide if it's moving or not.

Comment: actually the increment is 4190 km every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The units are meters (see [distanceTo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location))).

2) Yes. But like all programmers, you're still learning, so to be more helpful I won't just leave it there! The reason you are getting a huge distance is because your code is getting the distance between `locationA` and `locationB`, and you haven't set `locationB` at the time you execute the line:

```
float distance = locationA.distanceTo(locationB);
```

So you're getting the distance between `locationA` and lat/long 0,0.

You're only setting the latitude and longitude of `locationB` in your `Runnable` which will be executed after `distance` has been set. So, you probably need to move your distance calculation and the code that outputs it to within your `Runnable` that sets the latitude and longitude for `locationB`. You'll also have to make `locationA` `final` to do that.